# Program to remove all special characters from an input string and store alphabets in a new string

Tags: c++, string, loops

This is a program to remove all special characters from a string and store the alphabets in a but it doesn't store anything beyond the first space.
when the input is "Life is beautiful", the output is "Life".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string mes="";
string pas;
string tem;
cin>>tem;
cin>>pas;
for (int i=0;i<tem.length();i++){
    char c=tem[i];
    int ch=(int)c;
    if(( ch >= 65 && ch <= 90) || ( ch >= 97 && ch <= 122))
        mes+=c;
    else
        continue;
}
cout<<mes;
```

Comment: `std::cin` reads up to first whitespace character. You may want to use `std::getline`

Comment: Please don'y use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you by e.g. `65` mean the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) encoded character `'A'` then *say* so (i.e. use `'A'`). Or better yet, use [the standard character classification functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte#Character_classification) (like [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha)).

Comment: There's also no need for the `ch` temporary variable, or the `else continue;` part.

Comment: Lastly, `<string.h>` is *not* the file you need for `std::string`. It is the header-file for the C string functions. You want the [`<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string) header file.